# Video chat software for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, video, voip, chat, sip

Is there any video/audio chat program available for Ubuntu 9.4 apart from Skype  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ekiga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekiga) ? formaly known ans Gnome meeting.

Answer (score 1):

[Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) works with Ubuntu 9.04 but you have to update it with the Karmic sources. Then you can use your Jabber/Google talk account to video chat.

Answer (score 0):

[Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/):

> Linphone is an open source Voice Over IP phone (or SIP phone) that makes possible to communicate freely with people over the internet, with voice, video, and text instant messaging.
>
> Linphone makes use of the SIP protocol (an open standard for internet telephony) and can be used with any SIP VoIP operator, including our free SIP audio/video service.

See also:

- [Easy voice talk between 2 computers in 2 countries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150565/easy-voice-talk-between-2-computers-in-2-countries/151456#151456)