# Cross-platform video chat via XMPP

Tags: chat, xmpp, video-chat

I've seen some questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/61920/video-chat-software-for-ubuntu) about video chat on non-Windows platforms.  I'm specifically wondering about this in a corporate environment, using an internal server rather than one on the public Internet.

We already host a Jabber / XMPP instant-message service, though I'm not sure what the actual server software is because I'm not responsible for it.  From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/119569/open-source-chat-protocol-that-handles-voice-video) it looks like ejabberd is a good choice for the server if I have to stand up my own, but other suggestions are also welcome.  There's a lot of standards out there and I don't know which one is the best fit.

As for clients, I'm not sure what would support voice/video on both Linux and Windows (at least).  We've been using Pidgin but a) I don't have video support compiled in on the Linux side right now, and b) AFAICT the Windows version doesn't support v/v yet.  I'm not picky, I just need something that's going to work cross-platform -- I've had problems at home e.g. getting iChat to talk to Google Talk, etc.  I hope I'm asking the right questions... I'm kind of new to a lot of the terminology here.